# Intuition for sigma algebra representing information

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, intuition, conditional-expectation

I have a vague understanding of (sub)sigma-algebras in probability theory representing information, especially when conditioning. I want to make this intuition more exact. Suppose we are working in a probability space $(\Omega, F, P)$. I understand that $\{\emptyset,\Omega\}$ represents no information and that $F$ represents all "possible" information. For some specific other examples I also have intuition on their meaning. For a random variable $X$, $\sigma(X)$ represents knowing the value of $X$. For an event $A\in F$, $\sigma(1_A)=\{\emptyset, \Omega, A, A^c\}$ represents knowing whether $A$ happened or not.

Now I'm interested in how to interpret conditioning on some arbitrary (usually infinite) subsigma-algebra $G\subset F,$ but the intuition from the above examples seems to break down. I first suspected that we could interpret conditioning on $G$ as knowing for each event in $G$ whether it occurs or not, but this leads to problems. If we take for example $F$ to be the Borel sigma-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$, then this would mean that any sigma-algebra containing all singletons (which are often null sets) leads to "full knowledge". Since we could then for each point $x\in\mathbb{R}$ determine whether the event $\{x\}$ occurred, which should allow us to know exactly in which point of $\mathbb{R}$ we are. In particular, the sigma-algebra $H:=\sigma(\{x\in\mathbb{R}\})$ would contain all the information that the full Borel sigma-algebra $F$ contains. It seems to me that this cannot be the case, so I'm wondering how to solve this flaw in my understanding. What information does conditioning on $F$ give that $H$ does not?

I suspect that my intuition breaks down because sigma-algebras in principle only allow countable operations, but to know in what point $x\in\mathbb{R}$ I am, I need to check uncountably many singletons. Still, I'm having trouble formulating what the events in a conditioning sigma-algebra then represent in terms of information. It seems to be something like "you know of each event individually whether it occurs, but you can't combine this information for different events", which seems strange/unintuitive to me.

Comment: What is your $G$ in that middle paragraph exactly? The notation is sloppy in a way that creates ambiguity. But anyway, you are inevitably going to have some problems with intuition when you focus on particular $\omega$'s because the conditional expectation is only defined up to a.s. equivalence anyway.

Comment: (Cont.) In most concrete situations, what conditional expectation does is give you the $\mathcal{G}$-measurable variable which is closest to $X$ in the sense that their difference has the smallest possible $L^2$ norm, or in other words the means are the same and the variance of the difference is as small as possible. It's defined without this much integrability included, but incorporating this extra integrability helps with intuition.

Comment: (Cont.) The key theorem to interpreting what $\mathcal{G}$-measurability really means about information arises when $\mathcal{G}=\sigma(Y_1,\dots,Y_n)$, in which case a $\mathcal{G}$-measurable function can be given as a Borel measurable function of $Y_1,\dots,Y_n$. Sub-$\sigma$-algebras not of this form don't really come up in practice.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, @Ian. I understand the intuition that conditional expectation is a projection onto the space of (square integrable) $G$-measurable functions, but it's not clear to me how to interpret the conditioning sigma-algebra $G$ here. In particular, what information does it represent?

Comment: It is "the best guess" of the value of $X$ that you can make knowing whether $\omega \in A$ for all $A \in G$ with $P(A)>0$ and nothing else.

Comment: I'm also looking specifically for intuition for general sigma-algebras, not just those generated by a random variable. I do suppose that working $\omega$-wise leads to problems due to conditional expectation being defined only up to a.s. equivalence. Thanks, I hadn't considered that technical problem for the interpretation.

Comment: Honestly not much else really comes up in practice. By far the most common sub-$\sigma$-algebras that come up in practice are natural filtrations generated by some process.

Comment: @Ian I see, I suppose that answers my question. Thanks a lot! I'm going to play with this a bit more and see whether I properly understand.